# removing one of parameters from adress with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to remove unnecessary parameter from the URL.
URL looks like: `example.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=11824&category_id=5` and I need to remove `category_id` parameter by htaccess 301 redirect because it doesn't change anything no matter of given number.
I tried several formulas, my last try, based on my findings here and elsewhere in google is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\?page=shop\.product
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category_id
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

But nothing works, adress stil stays the same.
Mod_rewrite is on, before this I'm making 301 redirects using RewriteRules and everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?category_id=[^&]*(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the second time you're helping me. You're awesome :)